# error 1004, Method "Locked" on "Range" failed: VBA if cell1="" Then cell2=x

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating macro that should take values from one range and if blank, lock cells in another range.
I am still getting error 1004, Method "Locked" on "Range" failed.

```
Sub function_one()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("Table[[Column1]:[Column2]]")
        Dim cell2 As Range
        For Each cell2 In Range("Table2[[Column1]:[Column2]]")
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell2.Locked = True   
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Side note, but you probably don't want two loops here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot lock a locked cell.

So either unlock it first to be sure, or check it first and only lock it if not already locked.

To unlock first, one line of code added to do this, your original becomes:

```
Sub function_one()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("Table[[Column1]:[Column2]]")
        Dim cell2 As Range
        For Each cell2 In Range("Table2[[Column1]:[Column2]]")
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                cell2.Locked = False   
                cell2.Locked = True   
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Or, you could check if unlocked and only then lock it:

```
Sub function_one()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("Table[[Column1]:[Column2]]")
        Dim cell2 As Range
        For Each cell2 In Range("Table2[[Column1]:[Column2]]")
            If cell.Value = "" Then
                If cell2.Locked <> True then cell2.Locked = True   
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell
End Sub
```

In both examples, your code is not otherwise modified. There are a few things I too would do differently, including the `Table[[Column1]:[Column2]]` part, the nested loops, etc. but all that may be beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to loop through a collection of cells, a single
'For Each' loop is enough.

Secondly, `Range("Table[[Column1]:[Column2]]")` can be the reason why the bug occured. It is easy to use VBA `find` function to locate the range.

You might try the following code to see if it works:

```
Sub function_one()
    'By changing searchOrder, searchDirection, .Row and .Column to locate the firstRow, firstColumn and lastColumn
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchOrder:=xlByRows, searchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For Each cell In Range("A1", "C" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```